# ¿Cómo actualizar un elemento de un array en React?

Tags: reactjs

Usando ReactJS necesito actualizar un elemento de un array usando [los helpers de inmutabilidad](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/update.html).

Tengo algo como esto:

```js
this.setState(React.addons.update(this.state.collection[index], {
  property: { $set: !this.state.collection[index].property }
}));
```

En el que `index` es efectivamente el índice del elemento a modificar en la colección, y `property` un booleano que quiero negar en la actualización.

El problema es que el código no está modificando el `property` del elemento de la colección, si no que está generando una propiedad `property` en el objeto `this.state` - por lo que `this.state` termina siendo algo como `{collection: [...], property: true}`.

En [Nested Collections](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/update.html#nested-collections) dice que tendría que usar un hash con el índice del elemento como clave, pero yo tengo el índice en una variable, por lo que entiendo que queda ambiguo el update:

```js
this.setState(React.addons.update(this.state, {
  collection: {
    index: {
      property: { $set: !this.state.collection[index].property }
    }
  }
}));
```

Pero me dice que `Cannot read property 'property' of undefined` (es decir, `this.state.collection` no tiene una property `index`, que es entendible).

**¿Cómo puedo resolver esto?**

Se que debería usar `$apply` en lugar de `$update`, pero ese no es el punto de la pregunta :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[En StackOverflow en inglés](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34211520/641451), [Felix Kling](https://stackoverflow.com/users/218196/felix-kling) me contestó que se pueden usar las propiedades dinámicas de ES2015:

```js
this.setState(React.addons.update(this.state, {
  collection: {
    [index]: { // <--
      property: { $set: !this.state.collection[index].property }
    }
  }
}));
```